# Rails view returning database field after loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view I do this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <%= JSON.parse(current_printer.stripe_managed_account.fields_needed).each do |f| %>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= f.gsub!(/[._]/, ' ')  %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

It lists everything out like it should, but then at the end it returns the value of `current_printer.stripe_managed_account.fields_needed`. I'm not sure why it does this, or how to prevent it from doing this.

This is a screenshot:

[image: list]

Comment: Why would you down vote this question?

Comment: Remove equals sign from `<%= JSON.parse`.  The equals sign says print the result returned by `JSON.parse` method.

Comment: @vee add an asnwer and I will accept.  good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<%= %>`, on your each line by `<%  %>`.

Because `<%= #your each %>` is same that : `<% puts #your each %>`.

Try this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <% JSON.parse(current_printer.stripe_managed_account.fields_needed).each do |f| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= f.gsub!(/[._]/, ' ')  %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Thanks @vee